# Are there any electro-osmosis damp proofing systems that work?

Tags: walls, moisture

I have a problem with rising damp in an old wall and am wondering if electro-osmosis damp proofing systems actually work to remedy this as they claim. The type of system I'm talking about consists of a wall-mounted electromagnetic field generator and a cathode in the ground. The system is supposed to cause the water to move back into the ground by reversing its polarity. [This](http://www.drymatportugal.com/index.html) is an example of such system.

[image: Illustration of an electro-osmosis damp proofing system]

Naturally, I'm skeptical about the claimed efficiency of this, but I'm no expert. From googling, it seems that many (all?) electro-osmosis systems are useless, but they are of different configuration than the one described here. On the other hand, some people claim they work for them, but it's hard to evaluate if this is due to the actual system, or if there were other repairs involved.

Are these systems legit?

Comment: Sets my snake-oil detector off, but I don't have any more definitive evidence to refute with.

Comment: I have come accross few scientific papers from Denmark, Czech and Russian universities confirming effectivity of such methods. 
I'm planning to install such device myself. I will definitely post my experience.

Comment: Even if such a device worked, wouldn't the electromagnetic field interfere with things like electronics? Namely my ever so important wifi, computers, TV, elderly with pacemakers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two sides to an answer for your question you must consider.
First, it is important that you properly identify the type of damp. Rising damp should not be mistaken by penetrating damp or condensation damp. For clear description, please have a look here: https://www.wisepropertycare.com/services/rising-damp/what-is-rising-damp/signs/

Secondly, electro-osmosis works, as far as the physical processes behind it. It is therefore industry-accepted. I can send you a study made for one such product. Electro-osmosis is used in various dehydration processes, such as sludge dehydration by a Japanese company Kurita, proving its efficiency.

It seems that negative reviews about this technology have two sources: one is wrong diagnosis of rising damp prior to instalation of electro-osmosis devices, and another is poor quality of the device or poor quality of its installation. Most electro-osmosis kits contain titanium anodes which must be drilled into the wall, which is handled unprofessionaly, weakens the end result. There are also completely non-intrusive devices on the market which are plugged into the socket and provide the same effect, i.e. repel water molecules from the walls and force them back into the soil. This French company provides such devices: http://build-innovation.com/en/

Hope this answer clarifies your doubt about electro-osmosis for rising damp.

Comment: "I can send you a study made for one such product." - can you give a reference, does it have a doi?

Comment: I was reading 2 papers: "[Wireless Electro Osmosis](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/283776839_Wireless_Electro_Osmosis)" from _Slovak University of Technology in Bratislava_, and "[Does electro-osmosis work in moisture damage prevention?](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324790048_Does_electro-osmosis_work_in_moisture_damage_prevention_Applicability_of_infrared-based_methods_to_verify_water_distribution_under_electric_fields)", from _University of Milan_, and **both conclude it doesn't work**. That makes me doubt. Could you note some methodological error?

Answer (score 1):

No use in my experience, but maybe you could post some pics of the wall in question?

I've found that actual rising damp is quite often misdiagnosed. More often it's the gradual rising of the outside ground level, poorly managed rainwater and surface water or even internal living conditions to name a few. Sometimes the walls joints are cracked or eroded and are letting in water too.

I was called out once to look at a 'damp' problem and the lady was drying a mountain of clothes inside, had every vent in the house blocked off (to stop drafts), was boiling goodness knows what on all 4 hob rings and had turned off the heating because 'she was too hot'..... Condensation running down the walls....little bit.